# How do you assign a label, when using set object circle in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to assign a label to a specific point that I draw with

```
set object circle at first 3,3 radius char 1.5 fill color rgb "red" fillstyle solid no border
```

I can't find any way to actually draw a circle with set object, and also assign a label to it, without being forced to create a separate label and place it manually beside the point.

IS there a simple way to just plot a single point with a label, beside set object circle and a separate label? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For your special case of a circle, you can use `set label ... point pointtype ...` to attach a point from the available `pointtype`s to the label:

```
set label 'mylabel' at 0,0 left offset char 2,0 point pointtype 7 pointsize 5 lc rgb 'blue'
plot x
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply; so the label origin will be the center of the point that you create? And with the offset, you move the label away from the origin so it can be read? Nice!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, its not possible.  Even the [demo script](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/rectangle.html) uses a label and a object separately.  You could define your own macros though (this example uses boxes not circles):

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p

set macro

labelMacro(i,x,y,l) = sprintf('set obj %d rect at %f,%f size char strlen("%s"), char 1; set label %d at %f,%f "%s" front center', i, x, y, l, i, x, y, l)

label1 = labelMacro(1, 0, 0, "Hello World")
label2 = labelMacro(2, -2, -2, "Hello World")
label3 = labelMacro(3, 2, 2, "Hello World")
label4 = labelMacro(4, -2, 2, "Hello World")
@label1; @label2; @label3; @label4;

set xrange [-5:5]
plot x
```

The above code produces the following graph:

[image: Graph with macro boxes]

Comment: Bummer; It would be convenient to use a label attached to an object, instead than derive all the time the position and attach to it a label. When you plot you can use "with label" but it won't work for a single object. Thanks!

Comment: Fortunately, for this special case of putting frames around labels, there is the new parameter `boxed` in the upcoming 5.0 release: `set label 'label' at 0,0 boxed`.

Answer (score 2):

In gnuplot labels and objects are different things, they occupy different "namespaces".

@ilent2's answer is workable, with the small modification that instead of macros you can use eval:

```
labelMacro(i,x,y,l) = sprintf('set obj %d rect at %f,%f size char strlen("%s"), char 1; set label %d at %f,%f "%s" front center', i, x, y, l, i, x, y, l)

eval labelMacro(1, 0, 0, "Hello World")
```

Relatively new versions of gnuplot also have boxed labels:

```
set label 137 "foo" boxed
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `eval`, much cleaner then storing the string and evaluating the macro on two separate lines.